# variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays sd[16][16] and gd[16][16] in javascript. I need to compare the values of the arrays.

```
var score=0;
document.write("<table>");
for(c1=0; c1<16; c1++)
{   document.write("<tr>");
    for(c2=0; c2<16; c2++)
        document.write("<td onClick='changeColor(this);'>" + gd[c1][c2] + "</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");

function changeColor(tdd)
{
    if(tdd.bgColor=='white')
    {
        tdd.bgColor='red'; 
        if (gd[c1][c2] == sd[c1][c2])
            score+=5; 
        else
            score-=2; 
    }
    else
    {
        tdd.bgColor='white'; 
    }
}
```

However, when I try to display the score later, the score is not displayed.

```
function scc()
{
    document.getElementById('scf').innerHTML = score;
}
</script>
<br><br><center><button type='button' onclick='scc()'> Click to see current score</button> <p id="scf">0</p> </center>
<br><br> <center><input type="submit" value="Get Solution"/></center>
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Be sure  to initialize "score" as a global variable outside if your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little more work but you could use a closure to keep the score variable isolated.

```
var score = (function () {
    var currentScore = 0;
    return {
        getScore: function() { return currentScore; },
        updateScore: function(change) { currentScore += change; }
    }
})()
```

and then you can get/set the score like this: `score.getScore();` and `score.updateScore(5); score.updateScore(-4)`

This way you don't have to worry about stepping on your score accidentally.

Comment: After the function, it seems you put an extra set of brackets at the end or are those necessary?

Comment: Not sure what brackets `[]`? you're referring to.  Maybe you mean the trailing parenthesis `()`? on the last line.  Those are so the anonymous function you just defined will call itself and return the object with `getScore:` and `updateScore:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to initialize the score-variable. Now you have the problem your score is only available in the changeColor-function. You can define a score-variable outside all the functions, so that it's available everywhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var score = 0;
document.write ...
</script>
```

Comment: I had already initialized score outside, but it is giving a problem.

Comment: The score is not getting displayed on clicking the 'Click to see score' button.